# Completing a circle in 60 seconds

Tags: time, drawing, geometry

I've been scratching my head for the last hour, but I can't figure out how it's done.

What I want to do is a timer shaped like a circle. The timer is set to 60 seconds. As the timer goes down, the circle in drawing segment by segment and when it's a full circle. The timer is at 0.

So, before drawing a new segment, the program has to wait some time so when it's done the timer is precisely at 0. But I can't figure out how to calculate this amount of time.

Any ideas ?

Here is the code, just in case

```
public void circle(float x, float y, float rad, float start, float end){

    float theta = start;

    float x2 = (float) (x + rad * Math.sin(theta));
    float y2 = (float) (y + rad * Math.cos(theta));

    theta -= 0.01f;

    timer.start();

    while(theta >= -end){
        float x1 = (float) (x + rad * Math.sin(theta));
        float y1 = (float) (y + rad * Math.cos(theta));

        ligne(x2, y2, x1, y1);
        theta -= 0.01f;


        x2 = x1;
        y2 = y1;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    timer.stop();
}
```

Comment: Is this Java? You should be sure to add a tag to your posts with the relevant language and or libraries you're using - it helps folks who are trying to understand your code. :)

Comment: Yes, this is java. But the language is actually not relevant. I'm pretty sure what I want to do is a simple calculus but I just can't figure it out